# Many to many linq query Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have three tables `Users`, `UserRoles`, `UserInRole`.

```
Users     UserInRole    UserRole
------    ----------    --------
Id        UserId        RoleId
Name      RoleId        Name
Email
```

I want to select user emails who is in **"admin"** or **"editor"** role.

```
var emails = userUnitOfWork.Repository.Select()
     .Where(u => u.UserRoles
     .All(r=>r.Name=="admin" || r.Name=="editor")).Select(t=>t.Email);
```

but that only returns one email that has no role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `and` of two [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.queryable.any(v=vs.100).aspx) conditions like this

```
var emails = userUnitOfWork.Repository.Select()
    .Where(u => u.UserRoles.Any(r => r.Name == "admin")
         && u.UserRoles.Any(r => r.Name == "editor"))
    .Select(t=>t.Email);
```

or a single [Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534807(v=vs.110).aspx) condition like this

```
var emails = userUnitOfWork.Repository.Select()
    .Where(u => u.UserRoles.Count(r => r.Name == "admin" || r.Name == "editor") == 2)
    .Select(t=>t.Email);
```

**UPDATE:** Your update (changing `and` to `or`) makes it trivial - just change `All` to `Any` in your original query.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `.All()` requires all items to match, this means that if the user has any roles other than "admin" or "editor" the result will be false.

a solution to this is to use `.Any()`

```
var emails = userUnitOfWork.Repository.Select()
.Where(
    u => u.UserRoles.Any(r=>r.Name=="admin")
    && u.UserRoles.Any(r =>r.Name =="editor")
)
.Select(t=>t.Email
```